# Installing flex (lexical analyzer) on Mac

Tags: c, macos, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

Can someone tell me how I can install flex (lexical analyzer) on my Mac? I searched everywhere on google and I can't find it. I have the universal binary and I extracted it to my desktop but I have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get the binary from? I can't find one on their site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use macports to install [flex](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=flex)

Answer (score 18):

Try using Homebrew (Packet manager for Mac) and use the following command :-

```
brew install flex
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always install from source. Download the tarball from [the flex site](http://github.com/westes/flex), extract it, cd to the directory where you extracted it, and run the following:

```
./configure
make
make install
make clean
```

Assuming you have make and a C compiler on your Mac, which I believe all Macs have.

Comment: Hey, i just did that there was bunch of text in terminal and i didn't see any errors. After that, I typed flex and path to the .lex file and nothing happened. Can you please tell me how I can use it? I searched on google and did exactly what i found. Thanks

Comment: @RafeKettler I've been trying to do exactly the same steps, but the `make` command keep erring out saying `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_yylex"`. Any idea what to try to fix this?

Comment: @Wongzigii I fixed that somehow. I'll try to remember how today, but no promises. I think, if I recall correctly I either didn't have one of my files `#include`'d correctly, or I was using an `extern` without defining it in the right place. But I get back to you if I remember the exact fix.

Answer (score 3):

Flex is shipped with the xCode Command line tools; you only got to install them via xcode > preferences > downloads > Command line tools. This also includes gcc (Clang).

Answer (score 0):

This info can help to somebody to save time:

Just today I have try to install FLEX 2.5.39 from sources.
Make - fails.

After some thoughts I have decide to try older archives.
2.5.38 - fail
2.5.37 - OK

It seems on now() = 2015-03-15, macport also uses 2.5.37 build.